# Mark Email as Read in Microsoft Graph SDK v5

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm stuck on a frustrating issue. I'm upgrading a service that monitors mailboxes that utilizes Microsoft Exchange in .NET Framework 4.6 to .NET 8 and I would like to use  [Microsoft Graph SDK v5](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md).

I would like to mark processed emails as read. Unfortunately, it seems like Graph v5 does not allow you to modify emails that are not drafts.

Here is a sample that I want to use to update the email, but I can't seem to find an applicable solution:

```
var emails = await GraphClient
.Users[EmailAddress]
.MailFolders["Inbox"]
.Messages
.GetAsync(
config =>
{
    //requestConfig
}
);

//Select first email

email.IsRead = true;

var result = await GraphClient
   .Users[EmailAddress]
   .MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages[email.Id].PatchAsync(email);
```

The SDK seems fairly limited and does not allow the consumer to update items programmatically. Is this just a limitation of the Graph SDK or am I missing something?

I'll have to fall back to the Graph API to achieve the ability to mark email items as read.

Comment: Does it throw any exception? What's the current behavior?

Comment: It throws an exception of "Message is not a draft."

Comment: Try to create a new instance of Message and set only IsRead property. Looks like some bug in the SDK. `var result = await GraphClient.Users[EmailAddress].MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages[email.Id].PatchAsync(new Message { IsRead = true });`

Answer (score 0):

User user2250152's answer worked for me.

```
var result = await GraphClient
       .Users[EmailAddress]
       .MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages[email.Id].PatchAsync(new Message()
       {
           IsRead = true
       });
```

Successfully updates the email message as read.